# Linkerd clusterNetworks for ExternalName service

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd

When I run `linkerd check --proxy` I get the next error:

```
 cluster networks contains all services
    the Linkerd clusterNetworks ["10.0.0.0/8,100.64.0.0/10,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16"] do not include svc my-namespace/postgres-database ()
    see https://linkerd.io/2.12/checks/#l5d-cluster-networks-pods for hints
```

The service in question has type `type: ExternalName` and should not be monitored by linkerd.

The official docs https://linkerd.io/2.12/checks/#l5d-cluster-networks-pods are not very helpful. ***To remedy this, update the clusterNetworks setting***. However, I did not find any information how clusterNetworks can be configured in Linkerd

This error appeared after the upgrade to Linkerd 2.12

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in linkerd 2.12 and should be fixed soon. https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/discussions/9814